# Class Methods with arrays…?

Tags: ios

I have a question regarding class methods. First here comes my code:

```
typedef enum Colors {
    PresetColorsWhite=0,
    PresetColorsBlue=1,
    PresetColorsLightGray=2,
    PresetColorsGray=3,
    PresetColorsRed=4,
    PresetColorsGreen=5,
    PresetColorsYellow=6,
    PresetColorsOrange=7,
    PresetColorsPurple=8,
    PresetColorsBrown=9,
} PresetColors;

    @interface PresetColor : NSObject

    @property UIColor *color;
    @property NSString *colorName;

    -(void)initWithPresetColor:(PresetColors)presetColor;
    -(NSArray *)getAllColorNames;
    -(UIColor *)getColorWithPresetColor:(PresetColors)presetColor;
```

And the implementation:

```
@interface PresetColor()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *colorArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *colorNamesArray;

@end

@implementation PresetColor

@synthesize color = _color;
@synthesize colorName = _colorName;

-(id)init{
    [self initWithPresetColor:PresetColorsWhite];
    return self;
}

-(void)initWithPresetColor:(PresetColors)presetColor{
    [self setupDictionaries];

    self.color = [self.colorArray objectAtIndex:presetColor];
    self.colorName = [self.colorNamesArray objectAtIndex:presetColor];
}

- (void)setupDictionaries {
    self.colorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor whiteColor] atIndex:PresetColorsWhite];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor blueColor] atIndex:PresetColorsBlue];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor lightGrayColor] atIndex:PresetColorsLightGray];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor grayColor] atIndex:PresetColorsGray];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor redColor] atIndex:PresetColorsRed];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor greenColor] atIndex:PresetColorsGreen];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor yellowColor] atIndex:PresetColorsYellow];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor orangeColor] atIndex:PresetColorsOrange];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor purpleColor] atIndex:PresetColorsPurple];
    [self.colorArray insertObject:[UIColor brownColor] atIndex:PresetColorsBrown];

    self.colorNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"White", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsWhite];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Blue", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsBlue];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"LightGray", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsLightGray];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Gray", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsGray];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Red", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsRed];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Green", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsGreen];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Yellow", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsYellow];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Orange", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsOrange];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Purple", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsPurple];
    [self.colorNamesArray insertObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Brown", nil) atIndex:PresetColorsBrown];
}

- (NSArray *)getAllColorNames {
    return [self.colorNamesArray copy];
}

- (UIColor *)getColorWithPresetColor:(PresetColors)presetColor{
    return [self.colorArray objectAtIndex:presetColor];
}
```

What I want to have in my app is the possibility for the user to select from some predefined colors. In the database only the integer from the typedef should be saved. 
Now I'm looking for the easiest way to save the Colors and ColorDescriptions in Arrays with the corresponding `typedef`'d `PresetColors` as key. Some methods should of course be for the object, but some should be class methods.
I mean the method -`(UIColor *)getColorWithPresetColor:(PresetColors)presetColor;` should actually be a class method etc. But how can I do that without everytime initializing the array? Of course I could make a complicated switch statement out of it, however I wondered if there is another way with arrays, so I only have one place where I set the keys to the objects and nowhere else? I hope it's clear what I mean :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you I would change the colorArray to a static instance like:

```
static NSArray *colorArray = nil;

+(NSArray *) colorArray
{
    if (colorArray == nil)
    {
        colorArray = @[[UIColor whiteColor], ...];
    }

    return colorArray;
}
```

then;

```
//This will work because you set enum values in the range 0 - 9 and btw those are the default values you don't need to set them explicitly
+(UIColor *)getColorWithPresetColor:(PresetColors)presetColor
{
    return colorArray[presetColor];
}
```